# Locating javascript references to html elements using an asp.net masterpage

Tags: javascript, asp.net, master-pages

Cannot figure out how to reference html elements in javascript when using an asp.net MasterPage.

I have done a good deal of searching, and I have found many examples which say this should be the way to do it. But thus far, when I try to implement any of them, I have been unsuccessful.

To summarize, by what I have found, this should NOT work:

```
document.getElementByID('txtLabel');
```

because the actual element at runtime gets renamed by asp.net to something along the lines of 'ctl00_MainContent_txtLabel', all of which I have found to be true.

Most of the solutions that I have found are of the form:

```
document.getElementByID('<%=txtLabel.ClientID%>');
```

The trouble is, I have not been able to get this to work either.

If I try the following:

```
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <script>
        var x = document.getElementById("<%=frm1.ClientID%>");
        console.log(x);
    </script>
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>ASP.NET</h1>
        <p class="lead">ASP.NET is a free web framework for building great Web sites and Web applications using HTML, CSS, and JavaScript.</p>
        <p><a href="http://www.asp.net" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Learn more &raquo;</a></p>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div id="frm1" class="col-md-4">
```

I am immediately greeted by a red squiggly from VS which states that

> The name 'frm1' does not exist in the current context

So if I try the following:

```
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <script>
        var x = document.getElementById("<%=frm1.ClientID%>");
        console.log(x);
    </script>
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>ASP.NET</h1>
        <p class="lead">ASP.NET is a free web framework for building great Web sites and Web applications using HTML, CSS, and JavaScript.</p>
        <p><a href="http://www.asp.net" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Learn more &raquo;</a></p>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <h2>Getting started</h2>
            <p>
                ASP.NET Web Forms lets you build dynamic websites using a familiar drag-and-drop, event-driven model.
            A design surface and hundreds of controls and components let you rapidly build sophisticated, powerful UI-driven sites with data access.
            </p>
            <p>
                <a class="btn btn-default" href="https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301948">Learn more &raquo;</a>
            </p>
            <p>
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="frm1"></asp:Label>
            </p>
        </div>
```

The red squiggly now disappears, but at runtime, looking at the JS console in Chrome, the result of the JS call is null.
JQuery is also returning the same confusing results to me. I cannot find a way to reference a control on the page.

I would like to be able to reference the controls on the page through JS, but I cannot figure out how to.

Comment: in your version #2, place `script` block *below* `<asp:Label runat="server" ID="frm1"></asp:Label>`. Bottom of the page is OK.

Comment: Hmm, so tried that, but putting it anywhere besides the top of the asp:Content section gives me `The type or namespace 'ProfileCommon' could not be found`

Comment: Ok, no, scratch that - apparently just a stupid VS spurious error. I went ahead and ran anyway and it cleared out, and now my result is non-null. Thanks